# Need to dynamically select menu option using the page title of the current page

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm working with a CMS that has me a bit handcuffed.

I need a select menu navigation that will be able to tell what state (Alaska, Alabama,etc.) page it is on, but I can only use the mark up presented on the HTML page to do so.

I created a select menu navigation that is constructed by parsing the structure of an existing UL.

This works fine, but it does not "remember" what page the user is currently on and just selects the first state.

So my thought was to take the page title (which will always be the state name) and compare it to the select value/text to select the necessary option in the select menu, but I've run into a roadblock.

This appears to be the sticking point:

```
$("div.dropDownNav select").val(":contains('" + pageTitleDis + "')");
```

Here's the code:

HTML

```
<div class='dropDownNav'>
    <select>
        <option value="http://www.lcl.com/cms/home/products/crop-hail-products/forms-rates-provisions/iowa">Iowa</option>
        <option value="http://www.lcl.com/cms/home/products/crop-hail-products/forms-rates-provisions/kansas">Kansas</option>
        <option value="http://www.lcl.com/cms/home/products/crop-hail-products/forms-rates-provisions/michigan">Michigan</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

Javascript

```
<script>
$(function () {
    var pageTitleDis = $(document).find("title").text();
    $('div.dropDownNav ul').each(function () {
        var select = $(document.createElement('select')).insertBefore($(this).hide());
        $('>li a', this).each(function () {          
            option = $(document.createElement('option')).appendTo(select).val(this.href).html($(this).html());
            $("div.dropDownNav select").val(":contains('" + pageTitleDis + "')");
        });    
        select.change(function () {
            //alert('url = ' + this.value );
            window.location.href = this.value;
        })
    });
})
</script>
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: where are the ul and li elements that are being iterated through? This current code won't even enter the first `each` method

Comment: What are you expecting `:contains` to do for you? I don't think you are using it correctly embedded inside the `val()`.

Answer (score 0):

This line is not a selector.

```
$("div.dropDownNav select").val(":contains('" + pageTitleDis + "')"); //wrong
```

There, you are assiging `":contains..."` as value.

Try:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     $('option[value*='+ pageTitleDis+ '").attr('selected','selected');
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/kLMM8/1/